# Bootable Windows Server 2016 USB Drive

Tags: windows, installation, windows-server-2016, usb-boot

I have 8 HP ProLiant DL380 servers that are mounted in a data center. I have to deploy Windows Server 2016 Datacenter operating system on all of them using a **particular customer's (modified) ISO**.

Unfortunately, the only way I can access this installation ISO is inside the DC security zone, which means I will have to create a bootable USB drive on-premise to install the farm. Another problem is that according to customer's SLA using any additional software for creating bootable drives is prohibited.
Is there any way of creating a Windows Server 2016 bootable USB using only native Windows 2016 Server tools?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forget this and mount and boot from the ISO image in iLO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. This can be done using native Windows commands like diskpart, bootsect and copy (xcopy).

Here are the guides that cover the topic exactly: 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/how-to-create-bootable-windows-server-2016-usb-thumb-drive-for-installing-os

http://itproguru.com/expert/2016/05/create-bootable-windows-server-2016-usb-thumb-drive-for-installing-os/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The first link is exactly what I need!

Comment: It would be better if you included the actual directions; links can and do go down.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 14):

That should be possible.

- Mount ISO image, say drive letter is x:
- Mount USB Drive, letter y:
- Run elevated `cmd`
- Run `diskpart` wipe the drive and create an active partition:
- Caution, this will wipe your disk! `list disk`, `select disk <nr. of pendrive>`, `clean`, `select partition 1`, `active`, `exit`
- Copy bootsector -> `x:`, `cd boot`, `bootsect /nt60 y:`
- Copy everything from ISO to thumb drive `xcopy x:\*.* y:\ /E /H /F`
- Done.

Handle with care and double check those commands!
This works for Server 2012 and should work for 2016, too.

Comment: This is golden! Man you should have a script and a blog page for that.

Comment: Well, I think this works from Server 2008 R2 onwards...

Comment: In my experience the USB drive needs to be formatted FAT32 and not NTFS in order to actually install off of for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: @JBaldridge [UEFI](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/20/creating-bootable-usb-drive-for-uefi-computers/) require the bootfiles placed on FAT32 partition.

Comment: `File creation error - The parameter is incorrect.` when trying to copy a large file to the FAT32 parition.  The file in question is 4.7GB `sources\install.wim` from the windows11 install iso.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that comes to mind is to use Microsofts own tool:
[Windows USB DVD tool](https://www.microsoft.com/da-dk/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)

Comment: I am afraid this one will not pass. The requirement is quite clear - usage of pure Windows 2016 only is allowed :-(